# Advanced Custom Fields update_value not triggering

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need an ACF select field to dictate the default value of another select field. To do this I thought I should use update_value set to the first select and when updated would set the default for the other field. But I can't get it to trigger no matter what I try. Example below is what I have in my functions.php

```
function action_acf_update_value() {
    print_r( 'See something' );
};

add_action( 'acf/update_value', 'action_acf_update_value', 10, 3 );
```

Any help or direction would be welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create ACF field, call it for example "dictate". Then your function would look like this:

```
function action_acf_update_value() {
    return( 'See something' );
};

add_action( 'acf/update_value/name=dictate', 'action_acf_update_value', 10, 3 );
```

That should populate your first select field. Let me know if that works and we'll go from there.